# backbone.marionette quit working

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, webpack

Being new to Webpack, i started some example side projects and got it working fine with Backbone, Marionette and Webpack.

Then I went to Disney for a week.  When I got back, I did a `npm update` and now "Backbone.Marionette" is undefined.  For each project!  I got one working through various shenanigans of messing with version numbers, but I don't understand what is going on, or how to fix it.

I've boiled it down to a primitive example:

```
window.$ = require('jquery');
window._ = require('underscore');
var BM = require('backbone.marionette');

console.log(Backbone);            // v1.2.3
console.log(Backbone.Marionette); // undefined?!
console.log(BM);                  // 2.4.4

var App = Backbone.Marionette.Application.extend({});
```

The `require` line pulls in Backbone just fine, but no longer does it define Backbone.Marionette, like it had before.  It *was* working.  I can likely get things working by just using that "BM" var, but I'd prefer to understand what happened.

I'm new to this webpack business.

Comment: Not all to familiar with webpack, but why don't you just use your `BM`-variable? :) `var App = BM.Application.extend({});`

Comment: because the Backbone.Marionette... method used to work, and i'd like to understand why things changed, rather than do a massive find&replace.

Comment: Also, some of the stuff within Marionette aren't working with that method, such as Backbone.Wreqr.

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't know the problem without seeing more of the code, I'm afraid. Using npm i always have to set e.g. Marionette or Wreqr myself. `Backbone.Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');`

Comment: I got it to work.  I cleared out, entirely, my `devDependencies` and `dependencies` and the `./node_modules` dir, and kept running it, installing any package it happened to be complaining about.  Eventually i got to the end of it's complaints, and the stupid thing worked.  So, an error in package.json or some incompatible version somewhere.  Who knows what it was.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work. I cleared out, entirely, my `devDependencies` and `dependencies` section of `package.json` and removed the `./node_modules` dir.  Then I kept running the app, installing any package it happened to be complaining about. Eventually i got to the end of it's complaints, and the stupid thing worked.

It turned out, `package.json` had both "backbone" and "backbone.marionette", so at some point, if `Backbone.Marionette` had already been initialized, it was evidently initializing `Backbone` too, wiping out any previous work.